# Proving that a cylinder's volume is equal to the sum of volumes of a sphere and cone

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I have to prove that a cylinder with the same height and width as a sphere and cone has the same volume as both the sphere and cone put together. Figured out that I had to put the formula into some algebra but not sure how to simplify it.
$$
\pi r^2 h = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 + \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h
$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to show
$$
\pi r^2 h = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 + \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h
$$
Cancel $\pi r^2$ from both sides (assuming $r \ne 0$) to get
$$
h = \frac{4r}{3} + \frac{h}{3}
$$
which implies $h = 2r$.

So if $r=0$ (in which case all volumes are $0$) or if $h = 2r$, you have the relationship you seek.